# Get return for the latest day

Tags: mysql

I am running a mysql - 10.1.39-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary- database.

I am having the following table:

```
| id | date                | product_name | close |
|----|---------------------|--------------|-------|
| 1  | 2019-08-07 00:00:00 | Product 1    | 806   |
| 2  | 2019-08-06 00:00:00 | Product 1    | 982   |
| 3  | 2019-08-05 00:00:00 | Product 1    | 64    |
| 4  | 2019-08-07 00:00:00 | Product 2    | 874   |
| 5  | 2019-08-06 00:00:00 | Product 2    | 739   |
| 6  | 2019-08-05 00:00:00 | Product 2    | 555   |
| 7  | 2019-08-07 00:00:00 | Product 3    | 762   |
| 8  | 2019-08-06 00:00:00 | Product 3    | 955   |
| 9  | 2019-08-05 00:00:00 | Product 3    | 573   |
```

I want to get the following output:

```
| id | date                | product_name | close | daily_return |
|----|---------------------|--------------|-------|--------------|
| 4  | 2019-08-07 00:00:00 | Product 2    | 874   | 0,182679296  |
| 1  | 2019-08-07 00:00:00 | Product 1    | 806   | -0,179226069 |
```

Basically I want ot get the `TOP 2 products` with the `highest return`. Whereas return is calculated by `(close_currentDay - close_previousDay)/close_previousDay` for each product.

I tried the following:

```
SELECT
    *,
    (
        CLOSE -(
        SELECT
            (t2.close)
        FROM
            prices t2
        WHERE
            t2.date < t1.date
        ORDER BY
            t2.date
        DESC
    LIMIT 1
    )
    ) /(
    SELECT
        (t2.close)
    FROM
        prices t2
    WHERE
        t2.date < t1.date
    ORDER BY
        t2.date
    DESC
LIMIT 1
) AS daily_return
FROM
    prices t1
WHERE DATE >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Which gives me the return for each `product_name`.

How to get the last `product_name` and sort this by the highest `daily_return?`

Comment: You have provided two conflicting specifications: `TOP 2 products with the highest return` AND `last product_name sorted by highest daily return`.

Comment: Can there be a situation when we don't have continues dates? Like after 5 we have directly 7 or 8 for a product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem Statement**: Find the `top 2 products` with the `highest returns` on the `latest date` i.e. max date in the table.

**Solution**:

- If you have an index on `date` field, it would be super fast.
- Scans table only once and also uses date filter(index would allow MySQL to only process rows of given date range only.
- A user-defined variable `@old_close` is used to find the return. Note here we need sorted data based on `product` and `date`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT
        prices.*,
      CAST((`close` - @old_close) / @old_close AS DECIMAL(20, 10))  AS daily_return, -- Use @old_case, currently it has value of old row, next column will set it to current close value.
      @old_close:= `close`    -- Set @old_close to close value of this row, so it can be used in next row
   FROM prices
   INNER JOIN (
        SELECT 
            DATE(MAX(`date`)) - INTERVAL 1 DAY AS date_from,  -- if you're not sure whether you have date before latest date or not, can keep date before 1/2/3 day.
            @old_close:= 0 as o_c
        FROM prices
    ) AS t ON prices.date >= t.date_from
   ORDER BY product_name, `date` ASC    
) AS tt
ORDER BY `date` DESC, daily_return DESC
LIMIT 2;
```

Another version which doesn't depend on this date parameter.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT
        prices.*,
        CAST((`close` - @old_close) / @old_close AS DECIMAL(20, 10))  AS daily_return, -- Use @old_case, currently it has value of old row, next column will set it to current close value.
        @old_close:= `close`    -- Set @old_close to close value of this row, so it can be used in next row
    FROM prices,
    (SELECT @old_close:= 0 as o_c) AS t 
    ORDER BY product_name, `date` ASC 
) AS tt
ORDER BY `date` DESC, daily_return DESC
LIMIT 2
```

Comment: @Anna.Klee, does my `problem statement` suits your requirement? If so, verify my answer, if not, let me know which scenarios we need to cover.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a self join:

```
select 
  p.*, 
  cast((p.close - pp.close) / pp.close as decimal(20, 10)) as daily_return 
from prices p left join prices pp
on p.product_name = pp.product_name 
   and pp.date = date_add(p.date, interval -1 day)
order by p.date desc, daily_return desc, p.product_name 
limit 2
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xfnpfWULKBLJurMgPKmRuV/4).
Results:

```
| id  | date                | product_name | close | daily_return |
| --- | ------------------- | ------------ | ----- | ------------ |
| 4   | 2019-08-07 00:00:00 | Product 2    | 874   | 0.182679296  |
| 1   | 2019-08-07 00:00:00 | Product 1    | 806   | -0.179226069 |
```

Comment: Thx a lot! Works perfectly! One trade of is, that the query seems to be quite slow on a large set of rows - I have over 10k rows in this table. Any suggestions how to make the query faster? I appreciate your reply!

Comment: Indexes on the columns `product_name` and `date` would help.

Comment: Maybe I am confused, how `-0.179226069` is the highest return for `Product 1`? It should be for id `2` where return would be `(982 -64)/64`. Let me know if i missed something.

Comment: @JitendraYadav You are right! I get null for the latest records!